# Where does sublime store themes?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've installed [itg.flat](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Theme%20-%20itg.flat) for sublime via the package manager. I'm wanting to make a few edits to theme but I can't find where package manager has installed the theme files. I'm using ST3 on OS X Mavericks

I've had a look around the net but haven't found anything relating specifically to what I'm after so a SO thread is a last resort.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Sublime Text 3 packages installed via [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) are by default stored as `.sublime-package` zip files in your `Packages` directory, whose location depends on your operating system:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`

The easiest way to edit them is to install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control. Once installed, open the Command Palette with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (OS X) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (Windows/Linux) and type in ***`prv`*** to access the ***P***ackage***R***esource***V***iewer options.

Select `Extract Package`, then scroll down to `Theme - itg.flat` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will extract the package into your `Packages` folder, which can be easily accessed via your operating system's file manager (Finder, Windows Explorer, Nautilus, etc.) by selecting **`Sublime Text → Preferences → Browse Packages…`** (this is for OS X, Windows and Linux have a separate **`Preferences`** menu). Any edits to the files in this directory will override the files contained in the `Installed Packages/Theme - itg.flat.sublime-package` file.

If you only wish to edit a single file, after typing ***`prv`*** into the Command Palette, chose `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` instead. You can then navigate through your packages and choose the file(s) you wish to edit - `Theme - itg.flat/itg.flat.dark.sublime-theme`, for example. Once you edit the file(s) you have chosen, they will be saved in the `Packages` directory,

However, please keep in mind that if the package is updated in the future, the changes will not apply because you've overridden them by extracting the files into `Packages`. This is not quite the case if you choose `Open Resource` - only the files you chose to edit and save will be stored in `Packages`, and they will override the identically-named file in the `.sublime-package` archive. If the package is updated in the future, the file(s) containing your edits will still override the same file(s) in the archive, but the rest of the files will be updated. For example, if you edit `itg.flat.dark.sublime-theme` via `Open Resource`, when the entire `Theme - itg.flat` is updated, your customized file will override the file of the same name in the package archive, but all other files will have the changes from the update applied.

Comment: It's ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/  for ST3 on MacOSX Sierra (for me at least).

Answer (score 3):

In st3 you can override packages by creating a same-name folder under ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/

For example, if you want to override the default theme:

- Open contents of Sublime Text.app (right clic > show package content), locate Contents/MacOS/Packages/Theme - Default.sublime-package
- .sublime-package files are zip, so copy the file somewhere outside, unzip it, locate the Default.sublime-theme file. It's json.
- Do your edits to the file
- Navigate to ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/, create a 'Theme - Default' folder
- Copy your Default.sublime-theme into the folder you just created

Done. Any edits you'll do to Default.sublime-theme will be auto-loaded in your current theme, no need to restart ST.

For reference:

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/packages.html

Answer (score 0):

Additional notes and what I've found:

Thank you all for the notes. What my portable install looks like (in location):

- C:\Users\xxxxxx\Downloads\Sublime Text Build 3065 x64\Packages\Color
  Scheme - Default.sublime-package

What you're looking for:

- It's the Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package  this contains all
  of the themes.
  What to do next:
- Rename .sublime-package to .zip

  i.e. Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package to Color Scheme -
  Default.zip

  Unzip that zip file.

In the folder you should see:

- [content of the Color Scheme - Default folder of Sublime Text 3 Build
  3126 themes windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YSlw.png)