# Why do Sublime Text 3 Themes not affect the sidebar?

Tags: themes, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sidebar

I generally only use dark themes for coding, so it's really annoying that Sublime Text 3's sidebar stays light themed whatever theme you apply.

Does anyone know how to change this?

My configuration: Mac OSX 10.10.1 Yosemite, Sublime Text 3 Stable Channel, Build 3065

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reformat HTML code using Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set default syntax to different filetype in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The most recent version of Sublime has fixed this issue, click on Preferences, click on Theme select **Adaptive.sublime-theme**. This will change the sidebar to a dark colored background.

Comment: This answer really helps because without adding anything you can change the sidebar appearance.

Comment: Wow, this is great - why is it not more obvious to enable?

Answer (score 129):

You are looking for a **Sublime UI Theme**, which modifies Sublime's User Interface (e.g.: side bar). It's different from a Color Theme/Scheme, which modifies only the code part of Sublime's window. I tested a lot of UI Themes and the one I liked the most was [Theme - Soda](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Soda). You can install it using Sublime's Package Control. To enable it, go to *Preferences >> Settings - User* and add this line:

```
"theme": "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme",
```

Here is a printscreen of my Sublime Text 3 with Soda Dark UI Theme and Twilight default Color Scheme:

[image]

Comment: This helped me! I had installed Soda theme earlier but uninstalled instantly, horrified at the broken tabs and font anti-aliasing. But seeing your answer made me install it again and restart ST3 - and whoa, my life was never the same again! :D

Comment: Good answer. I didn't catch that the OP was using *color schemes*, not UI themes.

Comment: By the way, if you like Sublime, you should try Atom. It's open source, has the same Sublime features, is a lot better organized (there is even a Settings GUI) and more beautiful by default.

Comment: @Jay answer is the way to go, but if you're like me and stuck with an older sublime text version on Centos 6, then you can manually install this plugin by selecting _Preferences >> Browse Packages..._ and then from the `Packages` directory clone this theme: `git clone https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/ "Theme - Soda"`. Then make the changes to the user settings as described in this answer.

Comment: In my sublime3 build 3175, just click on Preferences->Theme then select "Adaptive.sublime-theme", the sidebar goes dark.

Answer (score 40):

You can manually change the sidebar style by editing Default.sublime-theme.

To do this, edit the “sidebar_tree”, “sidebar_heading” etc., classes in Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme. You can override those defaults by putting this [Default.sublime-theme](https://gist.github.com/MrDrews/5434948) inside the Packages/User folder.

From the Sublime Text menu, selecting “Preferences → Browse Packages…” will take you to it.

Comment: Where can I find Default.sublime-theme? In ST3 there is no Theme - default folder inside the packages folder.

Comment: From the sublime text menu, selecting “Preferences → Browse Packages…” will take you to it.

Comment: It takes me to a folder named "Packages" with the following subfolders:

- bz2
- Colorsublime - Themes
- PyV8
- Terminal
- User

None of those folders - or their subfolders - contains a file named `Default.sublime-theme`.

Comment: You are right follow the hiperlink. And put the file int he folder. Than restart sublime as @MattDMo says

Comment: Hadn't noticed the hyperlink. Thx for the help, bro!

Comment: You don't need to use these workarounds. The best way to smoothly merge a dark color scheme with the side bar appearance is installing a dark UI Theme for Sublime. Check my answer for more details.

Comment: @Pere my sidebar changed to brown instead of black, also nowhere you have mentioned that file needs to be copied. It turned brown after copying.

Comment: You can change the sidebar background color (aka tint) in the `Default.sublime-theme` by searching for `class": "sidebar_tree",` and modifying the `"layer0.tint"` values [R, G, B]. Make it black with [0,0,0] or whatever else you please, @garg10may .

Comment: I use this workaround because Visual Studio Dark doesn't sidebar UI coloring. If anyone is using this and cant get the "selected row background" in the tree colored properly, its         // Sidebar row selected
    {
        "class": "tree_row",
        "attributes": ["selected"],
        "layer0.opacity": 0.55
    },

Answer (score 19):

You need to restart Sublime completely in order for a theme to fully take effect. Just changing and saving `Preferences.sublime-settings` or using a theme-changing plugin won't do it. You need to use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> or `Sublime Text -> Quit`, not just close the window by clicking the red dot.

Comment: Ofc I have done that. The sidebar never changes, whatever theme I apply.

Comment: Restarting Sublime won't change the side bar. You need to install an UI Theme in order to change side bar appearance. Look at my answer.

Comment: Sublime3, build 3114 needed a restart before sidebar was black

Answer (score 14):

I thought I would put a note here that explains a basic misconception for a lot of people who are using these Text Editors... Sublime Text in particular (or at least that's the one I use, so I don't know how it works for other editors):

There are "Themes" and there are "Color Schemes". They are similar but affect different things. "Themes" actively change the entire UI, and can include a Color Scheme if you set it up that way. This typically includes the sidebar, and can also include options for the file tabs, and some even include icons for the sidebar as well. And then we have "Color Schemes" which only change the coding windows and nothing else... not the Sidebar, nor the File tabs, etc.

The confusion happens because some people call Color Schemes "Themes" which makes folks think that their "Theme" is going to change everything.... when technically, it's just a color scheme.

And an additional note: Themes don't automatically install for all users. When I install a Theme, I have to open my User preferences (under "preferences > Settings - User"), and then you have to add the line which says something like:

```
"theme": "Theme-Name.sublime-theme"
```

(where "Theme-Name" is the name of your theme).

This is different than just activating a color scheme. If you've chosen a color scheme via the dropdown menus in Sublime Text, you will see a line in there like this:

```
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color-Scheme-Name.tmTheme"
```

(where "Color-Scheme-Name" is the name of your color scheme).

Answer (score 12):

Here's the short version:

1. `.sublime-theme` files change the look of the UI including the Sidebar and File Tabs.
2. Defining these are a tremendous pain, so save yourself a lot of time and install the [Theme Menu Switcher](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Themes%20Menu%20Switcher) package.

***Update:*** Sublime Text 3 has fundamentally changed the way Color Schemes and Themes work, and has broken many of the packages that were built to handle them. I can no longer confirm the accuracy of this post, nor the functionality of the packages mentioned herein because the Sublime developers have not fully explained the changes to the customization system nor addressed how to fix them. And, at the very best, they are far more difficult to change.

*At this point, this post should only be used as a reference to the differences between "themes" and "color schemes" in Sublime Text 2, as I myself have yet to successfully change a theme nor color scheme in Sublime Text 3.*

*I will update this post as I can dedicate more time to unraveling this Sublime Customization Quagmire.*

---

## *Here's the long version:*

[image: tmTheme vs sublime-theme file type affection areas]
<sub><sup>***Figure 1:*** The difference between "Color Schemes" and "Themes" - In the Sublime Community these terms are often confused and used interchangeably.</sup></sub>

Changing the look of Sublime is a relatively difficult endeavor, for three main reasons:

- Poorly chosen terminology
- Misinformation in the Sublime Community
- Installation Nightmare

### ***Terminology***

There are 2 different sections of Sublime that can be customized:

- the *editable region* (the purple regions)
- the *User Interface* (the green regions)

These use two different file types, and they do not accurately reflect the terminology.

The "*Why?*" of this decision is compatibility, and for brevity's sake I won't get into it here, but the fallout of this effort is:

> The file type called `tmTheme` does not affect the theme, it affects the ***Color Scheme***.

***Color Schemes*** *(highlighted in purple)*

- affect the look of the editable region (more specifically, the editable characters, ie what color they are when highlighted or not highlighted, etc).
- relatively easy to produce
- Color Schemes are Mistakenly called "Themes" all over the Sublime Community.

***Themes*** *(highlighted in green)*

- `.sublime-theme` files change the Theme, or the UI aspects of Sublime.
- difficult to produce
- It is difficult to find true Sublime Themes, compared to "Color Schemes"

### *Misinformation*

Many packages claim to change the Theme, but actually change the Color Scheme. This is usually because the people producing them don't know that "Theme" specifically refers to the UI.

So another level of difficulty is finding a true "Theme" package, rather than Color Scheme.

Even some legit websites do not correctly make a distinction between the two, which adds to the challenges. For instance, [colorsublime.com](http://colorsublime.com/how-to-install-a-theme) has a tutorial on changing the sublime "theme", but actually references the "Color Scheme" file type (`.tmTheme`).

### *Installation Pains*

Themes and Color Schemes are hard to install and define. In fact, it's shocking how difficult the process is. The difficulty is further exacerbated with a fundamental change in installation and definition requirements in Sublime Text 3 that are not fully explained, which breaks many of the packages we once were reliant upon to change the Themes and Color Schemes.

It requires installing an actual Theme package (good luck finding one by browsing Packages in Package Control), defining it in settings, and then restarting Sublime. And, if you did something wrong, Sublime will simply replace your user-defined theme setting with the default. Yes, you heard me right, without notice or error message, Sublime will overwrite your theme definition.

But with [Themes Menu Switcher](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Themes%20Menu%20Switcher) All you need to do is go to `Preferences` > `Theme` and you'll see a list of all themes you have installed. You can also easily switch between themes without restarting Sublime.

Here's a sample from the website:[image: Theme Switcher gif]

I have no affiliation with Theme Menu Switcher at all, I'm just a fan.

*Again, Theme Menu Switcher does not work the same in Sublime Text 3. If you need to have a customized look, I recommend not to update to Sublime Text 3.*

Answer (score 5):

I first thought I was using SBT 3, then realized I was using version 2 still....

---

I finally got the sidebar to be dark on Windows!

I noticed that when I had my user settings theme set to "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme" it would half-way work but you could not see the folder structure. So I decided to try the other option in the Theme - Soda folder without the "3" and it worked right away. This should work below in your Preferences > Settings - User file.

```
{   
    "theme": "Soda Dark.sublime-theme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To Sidebar ceased to be white:

1. Download default theme because it is not in the folder sublime link here [by default.sublime-Theme](https://github.com/eneko89/sublime-monokai-sidebar)
2. In sublime 3 preferences -- > > Browse package
3. create a folder called "default theme" and put the downloaded file

if you installed the theme setUI, setUI file.sublime-the theme is looking for the line with comment:

```
"// sidebar || BG of selected files"
```

and under it a string

```
"layer0. opacity: { "target": 0.0, "speed": 50.0, "interpolation": "smoothstep" }
replaceable target": 0.0 --> target": 1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

setting `color_scheme` only sets the code pallet, 
setting `theme` sets the whole ST3 theme to the one you specify:

```
{
    "theme": "Nil.sublime-theme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Nil/Big Duo.tmTheme"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do this is : 
Go to Preferences -> Package Settings -> Your Theme Name -> Activation

In my case I installed Boxy Theme so the path will be 
Preferences -> Package Settings -> Boxy Theme -> Activation

Then there will be a pop-up menu that will let you choose which type of the theme package you want to activate. 
Use up and down arrow so choose then press enter or simply click the one you want to choose.

This is steps only applicable if the theme installed also customized the sublime text 3 sidebar.

Hope it help anyone!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to enhance your experience and change the sidebar and theme of the sublime text UI is to install two packages to control it:

1. Install a theme that has UI inside its package (I use Agila Theme [dracula] )
2. Install Themes Menu Switcher package

After you've installed those two, just change the color scheme (text editor) 
and then with the Theme Menu Switcher you'll switch to whatever UI you use.

Remember:
**It's required that the theme you install to have UI inside the package.**

Answer (score 0):

Just install package **Synced​Sidebar​Bg**:it will change the sidebar theme based on current color scheme.But it seems that every time you change the color scheme,sidebar will be changed after you open file **Preferences.sublime-settings**

Answer (score -1):

In Material theme 3.1.4 you can change theme like this: Tools->Metherial Theme->Material Theme Config. Its very easy.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. 
Just set the theme in Preferences -> Settings – User by editing the json property called.

```
{
    // Default theme
    "theme": "Material-Theme.sublime-theme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme"
}
```

For Material theme that I use. 
It worked for me.