# sublime text - git plugin for colorizing files on sidebar

Tags: git, file, colors, sublimetext3, sidebar

Is there a sublime text plugin that colorize directory/files like on Atom Editor ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Sublime Text 3 Themes not affect the sidebar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931448/why-do-sublime-text-3-themes-not-affect-the-sidebar)

Comment: There is currently no API available for changing the colors of different entries in the side bar, so this is not possible at the present time.